# How to set hours, minutes, seconds for date object in android

Tags: android, date, kotlin, time

I have Date object like this -> Sat Jun 26 **00:00:00** IST 2021
I want to set hours, minutes, seconds like this -> Sat Jun 26 **23:59:59** IST 2021

In Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with Calendar.

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.time = Date() // Set your date object here
    
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23)
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59)
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59)
calendar.time // Your changed date object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Calendar` API in Java, Get a reference to calendar like below.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

You can use the below methods to set minute and hour

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
```

read more about `Calendar` Api
[Oracal Docs Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
[Calandar Api example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calendar-class-in-java-with-examples/)

Answer (score -2):

Or use a **LocalDateTime** from **Java 8**

```
// change this to anything you want - Year.of(<int>)
val currentYear = Year.now().value
//  change this to anything you want - YearMonth.of(<year in int>, <month int value>)
val currentMonth = YearMonth.now()

LocalDateTime.of(currentYear, currentMonth.month.value, 26, 23, 59, 59)
```